# Intellij Idea iml file does not update

Tags: intellij-idea

When I want to change my module configurations via module settings, iml file of the project does not update related to revision. For your information no folder or file are read only. The weird thing is when I go back to module settings my last changes look without any problem I mean everything stands there as last configuration change and so it means I guess it writes all settings which I do into a file but where is it? why my iml file does not update anymore? Since this is happenning I need to change everything manually in iml file, I wonder that can anyone had experience fixing like these things?

Comment: If you close IntelliJ, does the iml file get updated?

Comment: no there is no any change

Comment: Have you checked for changes in the .idea directory?